# Python multiprocessing.Queue.get throws OSError (Handle is closed)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, python-multithreading

I have a Python Singleton class which exposes an API `put_msg_to_queue` to users. This API puts a string message to queue. The Singleton `Tester` class creates a thread which gets the message and just prints it.

Complete code used is given below. This code was working fine with `Python 3.9.12`, but seems broken with `Python 3.9.14`. The `queue.get` API throws `OSError` when process exits.

Other than handling this exception (the commented out code given below), please suggest how to adapt this code with new python version.

Probably below change mentioned in [changelog](https://docs.python.org/release/3.9.14/whatsnew/changelog.html#changelog) caused this change in behavior.

> Always close the read end of the pipe used by multiprocessing.Queue
> after the last write of buffered data to the write end of the pipe to
> avoid BrokenPipeError at garbage collection and at
> multiprocessing.Queue.close() calls. Patch by Géry Ogam.

```
# python -V
Python 3.9.12
#
# python sample.py
Closing..
Received msg: sample msg
cleaning
#
```

```
# python -V
Python 3.9.14
#
# python sample.py
Closing..
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/sample.py", line 32, in print_data
    record = self.myqueue.get(timeout=0.3)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 117, in get
    res = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 217, in recv_bytes
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 141, in _check_closed
    raise OSError("handle is closed")
OSError: handle is closed
#
```

```
# cat sample.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import queue
import multiprocessing
import time
import threading
import atexit

class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            return cls._instances[cls]

class Tester(metaclass = Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self._is_close = False
        atexit.register(self.close)
        self.myqueue = multiprocessing.Queue(-1)
        self.reader_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.print_data)
        self.reader_thread.daemon = True
        self.reader_thread.start()

    def put_msg_to_queue(self, msg):
        self.myqueue.put(msg)

    def print_data(self):
        while (not self._is_close):
            try:
                record = self.myqueue.get(timeout=0.3)
                print("Received msg: " + str(record))
            except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                raise
            except EOFError:
                break
            except queue.Empty:
                pass
            #except OSError as ex:
            #    if str(ex) == "handle is closed":
            #        print("Handle is closed, breaking")
            #        break

        print("cleaning")
        self.myqueue.close()
        self.myqueue.join_thread()

    def close(self):
        print("Closing..")
        self._is_close=True
        self.reader_thread.join(5.0)


tester = Tester()
tester.put_msg_to_queue("sample msg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be resolved if you do not use the call to `atexit.register` to do the closing of the queue but rather explicitly call it after all messages have been added:

```py
... # code omitted for brevity

tester = Tester()
tester.put_msg_to_queue("sample msg")
tester.close()
```

But you have so many timing dependencies and are using a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance with threading when all you need is  `queue.Queue` instance. So if I may suggest some changes:

First, you do have an error in your `Singleton` class: if the singleton has already been created (is in the `_instances` dictionary, your `__call__` method returns `None`.

Second, as I have already mentioned, you only need to use a `queue.Queue` instance since you are using multithreading.

Third, since your `reader_thread` method is a worker function for a *daemon* thread, it can do simple blocking calls in an infinite loop. To be sure that all messages placed on the queue have been read by this thread before exiting, you can call `join` on the queue. The thread must issue a call to `task_done` on the queue at the completion of processing each message it retrieves from the queue. In the following code all timing dependencies have been removed. The main thread can place as many messages on the queue it wants and the `reader_thread` can take as much time as it needs to process all messages. The program will not terminate until all messages by the `reader_thread` have been successfully processed.

```py
import queue
import threading
import atexit

class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Following did not belong with the if block:
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Tester(metaclass = Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        atexit.register(self.close)
        # Only need to use a queue.Queue:
        self.myqueue = queue.Queue(-1)
        self.reader_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.print_data)
        self.reader_thread.daemon = True
        self.reader_thread.start()

    def put_msg_to_queue(self, msg):
        self.myqueue.put(msg)

    def print_data(self):
        # Simplfied:
        while True:
            record = self.myqueue.get()
            print("Received msg: ", record)
            # Show message is processed
            self.myqueue.task_done()

    def close(self):
        print("Closing..")
        # Wait for all messages to be processed:
        self.myqueue.join()


tester = Tester()
tester.put_msg_to_queue("sample msg 1")
tester.put_msg_to_queue("sample msg 2")
tester.put_msg_to_queue("sample msg 3")
```

Prints:

```None
Closing..
Received msg:  sample msg 1
Received msg:  sample msg 2
Received msg:  sample msg 3
```